# Hadoop "hadoop dfsadmin command -triggerBlockReport"

Tags: hadoop

I triggered a command from `hdfs dfsadmin`

```
hadoop dfsadmin -triggerBlockReport
```

It gives me the output as

> Triggering a full block report on impc2390:50020.

Where should I find the block report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BlockReports are sent to Namenode from the Datanodes periodically (every `6 hours` by default). This command `hdfs dfsadmin -triggerBlockReport` is to send them on demand. These reports are not available as a local file for view.

You can use `hdfs fsck / -files -blocks` to view the block report of entire filesystem.

Comment: Thank you very much brother